# Integral of a certain form

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

How to compute or upper bound the integral $\int_{t=0}^{\infty} exp(-t^n-a(1-exp(-t^n)))dt$ for $a>0$, which is decaying with increasing $a$? I am primarily interested in $n = 1, 2$.

P.S. The above integration comes up while trying to bound expectations of the form $\mathbb{E}\left[\frac{1}{X^{1/n}}\right]$ provided $X>0$ w.p. 1. Therefore, a general recipe for this calculation will be interesting. Any other method that bounds the above expectation directly is of separate interest.

Comment: $n=1$ is easy:
$$
I_1(a)=\frac{1-e^{-a}}a
$$

Comment: Yeah I calculated that. But n>1 seems tricky.

Answer (score 0):

I have an approximation for the upper bound for $a>0$. The idea is to find a lower bound for the function $(1-exp(-x))$. I consider the following lower bound,
$(1-exp(-x))\geq x/2$ for $x\in [0,1]$ and $(1-exp(-x))\geq (1-1/e)$ otherwise. With this lower bound we can bound the term in consideration for $a>0$ as,

$\int_{t=0}^{\infty} exp(-t^n - a(1-exp(-t^n)))dt \\
\leq \int_{t=0}^{1} exp(-t^n(1+a/2))dt + exp(-a(1-1/e))\int_{t=1}^{\infty} exp(-t^n)dt\\
= \frac{1}{n} (1+a/2)^{-1/n} (\Gamma(1/n) -\Gamma(1/n, 1+a/2 )) 
+ exp(-a(1-1/e))\frac{1}{n}\Gamma(1/n, 1)
$

where $\Gamma(\cdot)$ is the gamma function and $\Gamma(\cdot, \cdot)$ is the incomplete gamma function.

The calculations can be tightened by considering other lower bounds for the above functions under this approach, which I have not tried out. However, the order of the decay w.r.t. $a$, i.e. $(1+a/2)^{-1/n}$, is order wise tight for large $a$. This is due to some relation with the expectation,  not elaborated here, mentioned in the question.